# Передать параметры SQL через запятую в Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, php7, mariadb

**Laravel Framework 5.6.29**

**PHP 7.2.11**

**mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.11-MariaDB**

Необходимо сделать SQL запрос с оператором IN. Данные необходимо взять из массива. Проблема в том, что запрос получается вида:

```
...IN ('123,312,111,222')
```

т.е. Laravel думает что это строка (это на самом деле строка, получаем с помощью implode). Необходимо каким-то образом передать туда что-то вроде списка. Пока решили таким кастылем:

```
foreach ($data['values'] as $key => $value) {
    $sql_string .= "AND id = $value ";
}
```

Есть более хорошее решение?

Comment: или так, но тоже не очень:foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 0)
        $sql_string .= "IN ($value ";
    else
        $sql_string .= " ,$value";
}
$sql_string .= ") ";

Comment: а если ему просто отдать массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так а в чём проблема использовать конструктор...

```
$result = Model::whereIn('id', $data['values'])->get();
```